# Checking if `if let` is nil

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, unwrap

I have an app where I'm currently using the [SwiftKeychainWrapper](https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper). Below is the code I have which checks if `retrievedString` is `nil`. However I'm still getting `retrievedString: nil` in the console.

Shouldn't the code in the if-let statement not run, or am I using/understanding if-let incorrectly?

With the given example, what's the correct way to use if-let to unwrap my optional value?

```
if let retrievedString: String? = KeychainWrapper.stringForKey("username") {
    print("retrievedString: \(retrievedString)")
    //value not nil
} else {
    //Value is nil
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because you are setting the value of a optional String, `String?` `KeychainWrapper.stringForKey("username")` to another optional String `retrievedString`.

By trying to set a `String?` to another `String?`, the if let check always succeeds, even when the value is `nil`, because both the types are the same, and both can accept a nil value.

Instead, you should attempt to set the optional string, `String?` to a non-optional string, `String`. When Swift tries to set a non-optional `String` to `nil`, it will fail, because a non-optional cannot have a nil value. The code will then continue in the `else` statement

You should use

```
//notice the removal of the question mark
//                            |
//                            v
if let retrievedString: String = KeychainWrapper.stringForKey("username") {
    print("retrievedString: \(retrievedString)")
    //value not nil
} else {
    //value is nil
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't need the ': String' at all. The compiler will infer that you want retrievedString to be a String because of the context.

Comment: Well explained. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You are setting the type of `retrievedString` to be optional. The whole point of the check is to remove the optional and just have a `String`.

```
if let retrievedString: String = KeychainWrapper.stringForKey("username") {
    print("retrievedString: \(retrievedString)")
    //value not nil
} else {
    //Value is nil
}
```